# Error loading Golang and Lua plugins in Kong

Tags: go, lua, kong, kong-plugin

I'm trying to install a new instance of Kong, but I'm getting the following error trying to start the service:

`stat /tmp/go-plugins/lua_plugin.so: no such file or directory`

The installation is supposed to install a plugin built using Golang and a plugin that is still written in Lua. If I remove the Lua plugin, the service starts up fine. The part that's confusing me is why is Kong assuming that both plugins are written in Golang? Other installations have worked fine, so it's very confusing why it's doing it now.

Comment: What does you kong config look like? According to https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/2.7.x/reference/external-plugins/#kong-gateway-plugin-server-configuration, kong will use the `pluginserver_go_query_cmd` command to query which plugins are available. It should pick were to look for a plugin based on the result of this query and which modules it can find in the `package.path` https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/2.7.x/plugin-development/file-structure/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the directory I was mounting in containing the lua plugins was not being mounted into the container properly. Specifically, the host path for the volume definitions, so fixing that resolved the issue.